# divide clock into halfs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

John has special clocks one hands do **1 turn per minute**, second do **1 turn per 3 minutes** and third do **1 turn per 15 minutes**. how many times and when the first **divide clockface into three equal parts** in first 15 minutes? How to get general solution?
sorry for my english

Comment: Do you even look at [tag:algebraic-geometry]? That's a topic way above your head judging from this question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
When they do that, the angles of the clock must satisfy
$$\theta_1 + \frac{2\pi}3 = \theta_2 = \theta_3 - \frac{2\pi}3 \pmod{2\pi}$$

Where $\theta_1(t) = \frac{2\pi}{15}t, \theta_2(t) = \frac{2\pi}3 t, \theta_3(t) = 2\pi t$ and $t\in [0,15]$

Comment: what means (mod ...) ????

Comment: That means that $2\pi$ is considered equal to $0$, $3\pi \equiv \pi$ etc. in general $a = b  \pmod c$ iff $b-a = kc$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$